# Laravel: Do one query update and then, if that succeeds, do the next, otherwise, do neither

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.1

So, I want to update two different user accounts with the same value.

Scenario: User 1 transfers money to User 2:

```
$transfer_from = $account->decrement('balance', $amount);

$transfer_to = Account::where('user_wallet_address', $receiver_wallet_address)->increment('balance', $amount);
```

But, what I want, is something like this:

```
$account->decrement('balance', $amount)->$transfer_to;
```

As in `if the decrement succeeds, then update the other user's balance, otherwise, both should fail`

Thoughts?

Comment: What you're looking for is a [database transaction](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/database#database-transactions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use database transaction feature

See below code example:

```
public function readRecord() {
    DB::beginTransaction();
    try {
        // put your code here in try block

         $transfer_from = $account->decrement('balance', $amount);
         $transfer_to = Account::where('user_wallet_address', $receiver_wallet_address)->increment('balance', $amount); 
        DB::commit();
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        // If any failure case generate, it will rollback the DB operations automatically.
        DB::rollBack();
        echo $ex->getMessage() . $ex->getLine();
    }
```

I hope this will help you. In this case if any failure case generate it will automatic revert the DB translocation and you don't need to do anything.

Reference URL: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/database